# Can't start mongodb

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I installed MongoDb on Ubuntu and was able to run it using `sudo service mongod start`. Then I had to restart it since I changes the config file. Now I can't start it again. When I run `sudo service mongod start`, it just says nothing (but I can't connect using `mongo`). And the log says,

`2018-06-06T18:45:49.279+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongodb, terminating`

Here are the permissions:

`ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-92:~$ stat /var/lib/mongodb
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: (  116/ mongodb)`

So, how do I run it again?

Bonus question: how do I make the command output the actual error, so that I don't have to look it up in the log every time?

P.S. I'm a long time Windows user, just learning Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Linux!

Second, I'm guessing in this case mongodb runs as the user `mongodb`

If this is the case, then the user mongodb needs permission to write to the directory.

Given your current permissions: the owner is `ubuntu` which can `rwx` read, write, and execute, while the group is `mongodb` which can only `r-x` read, execute. Since the mongodb user is in the mongodb group but does not own the file, it cannot write.

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/  ubuntu)   Gid: (  116/ mongodb)
```

To solve this either make mongodb the owner
`sudo chown mongodb:mongodb -R /var/lib/mongodb` 
or let the group write as well 
`sudo chmod 775 -R /var/lib/mongodb`

Assuming you installed the mongodb server using a standard method on standard linux system, you will likely need to restart the service using the systemctl (SystemD) or service (upstart) command.

SystemD: `sudo systemctl restart mongodb` or `sudo systemctl restart mongod`

Upstart: `sudo service mongod restart`

If you are running SystemD, then you can check the status of your service with

`sudo systemctl status mongodb` or `sudo systemctl status mongod`

And you can view the logs of your service with

`sudo journalctl -u mongodb` or `sudo journalctl -u mongod`